# A general fiber has nonsingular closure.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Assume $f:X\dashrightarrow Y$ is dominant rational map (of complex varieties), where $X$ is nonsingular, $Y$ is complete. I want to prove for *a general* $y$ in $Y$, the closure of the preimage of $y$ is also nonsingular.

In fact, I think I can prove it using Hironaka's theorem: there exists a sequence of smooth blowups $X_n\to X_{n-1} \to \cdots \to X_0=X$ such that $f_n:X_n\to Y$ becomes a morphism. Then, using generic smoothness of morphisms, a general fiber $f_n^{-1}(y)$ is nonsingular, hence in particular, nonsingular at the exceptional divisor, so $\overline{f_{n-1}^{-1}(y)}$ is nonsingular (**Edit**: I realized this is not correct, by Sasha's example). By induction we will finally prove $\overline{f^{-1}(y)}$ is nonsingular. However, this seems too overkill. Is there easier way to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Let $X = \mathbb{P}^2$ and let $\pi \colon \tilde{X} \to X$ be the blowup of the point $x_0 \in X$. Then $\tilde{X}$ is the Hirzebruch surface $F_1$, in particular there is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle $p \colon \tilde{X} \to \mathbb{P}^1$. Consider the composition
$$
f \colon X \stackrel{\pi^{-1}}\dashrightarrow \tilde{X} \stackrel{p}\to \mathbb{P}^1 \stackrel{q}\to \mathbb{P}^1 =: Y,
$$
where $q$ is a double covering (branched at two points). Then the closure of the general fiber of $f$ is the union of two lines through $x_0$; in particular it is singular.

Comment: Thank you for this nice counterexample. Will it be true if we replace "nonsingular" by "contains a nonsingular component"?

Comment: No. For instance, consider a pencil of cubic curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ singular at point $x_0$ and passing through points $x_1,\dots,x_5$ (in general position).

Comment: Could you explain a little more or give a reference on how this pencil is defined? Why cubic curves passing through five given points and singular at one point are parametrized by $\mathbb P^1$?

Comment: Just count parameters. Alternatively, if you blowup these six points you get a cubic surface $\tilde{X} \subset \mathbb{P}^3$. The preimage of $x_0$ is a line $L_0 \subset \tilde{X}$. Now, consider the linear projection $\tilde{X} \to \mathbb{P}^1$ out of $L_0$. Its fibers are conics in $\tilde{X}$ that intersect $L_0$ twice. Consequently, their images on $X = \mathbb{P}^2$ have singularity at $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you! I really like the second interpretation. One more question on this: in the last sentence, is there an easy way to show why their images on $X$ are really cubic curves?

Comment: Because the hyperplane class of the cubic surface is $3h - e_0 - e_1 - \dots - e_5$, the class of the line $L_0$ is $e_0$, hence the class of the residual conic is $3h - 2e_0 - e_1 - \dots - e_5$.